# Fstab mount error "mount: unknown filesystem type 'gid=33'

Tags: linux, fuse, sshfs

I am trying to use fuse and sshfs to mount a drive.  The command I use to do this is

```
sudo sshfs computer2@24.97.20.3:/Volumes/1TB\ Extra/MoodleMount /mnt/CampusServer -o allow_other,uid=33,gid=33
```

It mounts fine every time.  No password needed because the ssh keygen is saved on the server.  This is my fstab file.

```
/dev/xvda      /             ext3     defaults,errors=remount-ro,barrier=0 1 1
sshfs#computer2@24.97.20.3:/Volumes/1TB\040Extra/MoodleMount /mnt/CampusServer allow_other,uid=33,gid=33
```

I took out the -o because it was giving me more problems.  After I added the second line to the fstab file I get the following error when running "mount -a"

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'gid=33'
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've neglected to include the file system type in the fstab line.  You should use

```
sshfs#computer2@24.97.20.3:/Volumes/1TB\040Extra/MoodleMount /mnt/CampusServer fuse.sshfs allow_other,uid=33,gid=33
```

Comment: That seemed to work but now when I try to "ls" or "cd" the folder where it is mounted, I get this 'ls: cannot access CampusServer: Transport endpoint is not connected'

Comment: Also, when I first use 'mount -a' it  asks for a password.  I have entered the password for both the server and the client and have have no luck.  I than press 'Ctrl-C' when it asks for the password run 'mount -a' and I seems to work.  Than when I 'cd' or 'ls' to the folder I get the error above.